# How to control the number of threads when executing an Asynchronous Activity in WF 4

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I am creating a workflow in WF 4, where I have a `ParallelForeach` activity that iterates over a collection of items. For each item in the collection, I execute a custom Asynchronous activity to processing multiple items in parallel.

The above solution works for me, but I am concerned about the number of threads used since each Asynchronous activity instance is executed on its own thread.  Is there a way to configure/control the number of threads that get launched when executing the parallelForeach activity in the above described mechanism?

Answer (score 2):

*since each Asynchronous activity instance is getting executed on its own thread*.  Who says?  [Certainly not the docs.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee849842.aspx)

> ParallelForEach enumerates its values and schedules the Body for every value it enumerates on. It only schedules the Body. How the body executes depends on whether the Body goes idle.
>   If the Body does not go idle, it executes in a reverse order **because the scheduled activities are handled as a stack,** the last scheduled activity executes first.
>
> For example, if you have a collection of {1,2,3,4}in ParallelForEach and use a WriteLine as the body to write the value out. You have 4, 3, 2, 1 printed out in the console. This is because WriteLine does not go idle so after 4 WriteLine activities got scheduled, ***they executed using a stack behavior (first in last out)***.

The Parallelism of execution occurs only when an Activity creates a bookmark and goes idle.  Even then, two activities aren't actually executing at the same time--one or more have just stopped executing, allowing others to run in order.  Understandably confusing, given the name, but that's it.

In any event, when you're relying on the framework to parallelize for you, don't worry about how many threads they're using.  They probably have everything under control.  Until you know they don't.

Comment: Thanks Will! I did read the documentation about ParallelForEach before attempting my implementation. When I run my application, I do notice different Thread IDs being allocated for the actiity instances (and some threadIDs get reused because they come out of the threadpool).

Comment: @user1946680: Workflows run using a [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.hosting.workflowinstance.synchronizationcontext.aspx) to control their threading.  SC's have Send (synchronous) and Post (asynchronous) methods for executing code.  If you want, you can always create your own implementation and manage any calls to Post to restrict your threads.  I wouldn't advise it, as the framework's threading code is well written.  Its like worrying about memory management--don't, unless you absolutely have to.  They do it better.

Comment: Awesome! Thats good to know. For now, I will leave it as is and rely on the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Will is correct, ParallelForEach does not require a new thread for each branch. If you are doing blocking I/O in code that should occur in an AsyncCodeActivity so that you aren't unecessarily blocking. If you want CPU-bound work to run in parallel to other activities you will either need to wrap it in an AsyncCodeActivity or use InvokeMethod { RunAsynchronously = true} in which case the framework will take care of running the work on a background thread.

The SynchronizationContext extensibility point is intended for cases where you have a particular existing threading model that you need WF to integrate with. Prime examples of this include ASP.NET's threading environment, and Windows Presentation Foundation/WinForms (e.g. if you wanted a  activity to work correctly).